# Where can I find information and documentation on how to create "Custom scheduling" in Anki?

Tags: javascript

I don't like the standard behavior of anki. It is annoying to change the "ease" level and its STRONG effect on the result of the response buttons. I would like to do my own "Custom scheduling". A simple schedule where only the answer buttons affect the change of intervals, without the influence of the "ease" levels of the cards.

But I can't find documentation and educational information on this topic in any way.

I've been looking for a long time. That's all I found:

As far as I understand, the list of rpc requests. With minimal explanations.
https://github.com/ankitects/anki/blob/main/proto/anki/scheduler.proto
https://github.com/ankitects/anki/blob/main/proto/anki/ankidroid.proto

An example of the implementation of a third-party fsrs4anki schedule. For some reasons, there are much more explanations in code than in the examples above.
https://github.com/open-spaced-repetition/fsrs4anki

Most likely, I will have to look for more examples of someone else's code for "Custom scheduling". And to figure it out through experiments.